# How to add Leading Zeros in Sequence in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I have a column in my Table i.e. TieBreaker which accepts only 4 digits Length value.

I have wrote a SQL SEQUENCE to generate a Series :

/* Snippet to DELETE Existing Sequence*/

```
IF EXISTS 
    (
       SELECT * FROM Sys.Sequences WHERE Name = 'TieBreaker'
    )   DROP SEQUENCE TieBreaker
GO
```

/* Snippet to CREATE Sequence*/

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TieBreaker AS INT
 START WITH 0000
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 0000
 MAXVALUE 9999
 CYCLE
 GO
```

How can I output with Leading 0 for my sequence ? Like Below :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Your SEQUENCE start with 1000 and finishes with 9999?

Comment: @PeterRing Just updated my question, please review again!

Answer (score 2):

You do not. A number has no leading zeroes, as we all have learned in school.

The character formatting has. So you have 3 choices:

- Make the field a varchar. This is not totally off as many number sequences also have prefixes and ARE NOT NUMBERS.
- Add another computed field that formats the output so you can use that.
- Do not care on database level but format in whatever program uses it.

Comment: As SQL Server not allowing us to Use a Varchar Datatype in Sequence, I tried to use another computed column, But my Script is concatenating 2 other computed columns, thus SQL won't allow me to use them.  ERROR MESSAGE BY SQL SERVER : Msg 1759, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Computed column 'D_Tie Breaker' in table '#NonMon' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.

Comment: Well, yeah. I am sure you are unable to write a trigger or something to get a numeric value from a sequence, format it and put it into the inserted row?

Comment: I created a column SerialNumber, Inserting output of Sequence into it. Then i have another UPDATE Statement to insert the correct value in it...Its not the best solution, but it managed to get the job done! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An example of using a computed column for formatting

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  TieBreakerSeq INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR TieBreaker,
  TieBreakerAsChar AS FORMAT(TieBreakerSeq, '0000#'),
  SomeOtherData VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Test (SomeOtherData) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C')

SELECT * FROM Test

TieBreakerSeq TieBreakerAsChar SomeOtherData
------------- ---------------- -------------
0             00000            A
1             00001            B
2             00002            C
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Its perfect..But As I am using a #TempTable..I am getting an error i.e. Invalid object name 'TieBreaker'.< code>CREATE TABLE #Test 
(
  TieBreakerSeq INT, 
  TieBreakerAsChar AS FORMAT(TieBreakerSeq, '0000#'),
  SomeOtherData VARCHAR(10),
)
INSERT INTO #Test 
(
 TieBreakerSeq,
 SomeOtherData
)
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR TieBreaker, 'C'</code>

Comment: I didn't know about TieBreakerAsChar AS FORMAT(TieBreakerSeq, '0000#'), It will improve my code..Amazing ..Thank you Once Again !

Comment: One more method : SELECT  RIGHT ('0000' + CAST (NEXT VALUE FOR Invoice_Seq AS VARCHAR(5)), 4);

Answer (score 0):

did u try

```
select lpad(TieBreaker.nextval,'4','0') from dual;
```

it would give same result right?

```
0000
0001
0002 and so on..
```